# 'setCustomValidity' not defined in IE, it works in others

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, input

I have this input that work without problems in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE(I'm using IE11) it show this error: 'setCustomValidity' not defined, in all inputs. What could be the problem?

```
<input type=text name="surname" id="surname" class="inputsForm" placeholder="First Surname" required maxlength="100" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You must introduce your first surname')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Is Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode? (IE11 is reported to support that function)

Comment: I can't use any cfg to fix the problem in IE, it's going to be a public form and we want that the final user could use it without additional changes.